# Find an object in a nested set of objects and delete it

Tags: c#

I have the following classes (a little bit shortened) and try to delete one menu item:

```
public class LinkItem
{
    public string LinkName { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItem
{

    List<LinkItem> _LinkItems = new List<LinkItem>();
    List<MenuItem> _MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();

    public string MenuName { get; set; }

    public void AddLinkItem(LinkItem LinkItemToAdd)
    {
        LinkItems.Add(LinkItemToAdd);
    }

    public void DeleteLinkItem(LinkItem LinkItemToDelete)
    {
        LinkItems.Remove(LinkItemToDelete);
    }

    public void AddMenuItem(MenuItem MenuItemToAdd)
    {
        MenuItems.Add(MenuItemToAdd);
    }

    public void DeleteMenuItem(MenuItem MenuItemToDelete)
    {
        MenuItems.Remove(MenuItemToDelete);
    }

    public List<LinkItem> LinkItems
    {
        get { return _LinkItems; }
        set { _LinkItems = value; }
    }

    //private List<MenuItem> _ListOfMenuItems;

    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get { return _MenuItems; }
        set { _MenuItems = value; }
    }
}

public static class FullMenu
{
    static CompleteMenu()
    {
        _CompleteMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    }

    private static List<MenuItem> _MenuItems;

    public static List<MenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _CompleteMenuItems;
        }

        set
        {
            _CompleteMenuItems = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Then i add some items, the structure looks like:

> FullMenu
>   --> MenuItem1
>   ----> LinkItem1
>   -->
>   MenuItem2
>   ------>   SubMenuItem1
>   -------->
>   SubLinkItem1
>   ------>   LinkItem2
>   --> MenuItem3
>   ----> 
>   LinkItem3

So its a nested structure.

If i want to delete one MenuItem (e.g. SubMenuItem1) i have to find it in the nested structure to delete it.

Is there a way (with linq or lambda) to search for the MenuItem without looping through all items of FullMenu?

All things i've tried only find items in the first level of FullMenu.

Comment: Perhaps demonstrate what it was you tried and let's go from there?

Comment: No.  To reduce search time you could make a list<> object or dictionary that contains all the SubMenuItem, but you wouldn't be able to delete item unless the SubMenuItem class contain a property for the parent so you can remove item.

Comment: Linq can't do that. It's just a tree parsing. Just create a private method `RemoveMenu(string menuName)` in `MenuItem` and loop on all `_MenuItems` and if the item is the one your are looking for remove it otherwise call the child method `child.RemoveMenu(menuName)`

Comment: Just keep in mind that you can't modify a collection while you are looping though it with an enumerator.  That means you can't just delete the item as soon as you find the match from inside a `foreach` or implicit LINQ loop.

Answer (score 2):

Store whatever you add in a `Dictionary<string, object>` where `string` is something like id from which you can identify the item. `object` is the actual instance of `LinkItem` or `MenuItem`.

When you decide to delete an item, get the item from dictionary using key and just delete it.